# Extending The Tenant

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am looking to extend the Tenant functionality by creating a recursive relationship so that a Tenant may be a parent of many other Tenants.

For Example:

```
>Tenant A
  >Tenant B
  >Tenant C
     >Tenant D
```

Should I extend the Domain obj Tenant or is there already a way to achieve the above?

Comment: Currently there isn't a built-in way to achieve this. You can try adding ParentTenantId to the existing Tenant entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, #aspnetboilerplate team > the latest version does a nice job with Organization-Units to achieve what I need.